# What is wrong with this program to find out the primes between 1-n numbers?

Tags: c

This program is not giving any output for prime numbers.
What is the error in the code ? I have to use while loop only !

There are no compilation errors the program is executing fine but after taking a number as an input this program is not generating the prime numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

int num, i=1, j=1, count;

printf ("Enter the no. of terms :\n");
scanf ("%d", &num);

printf ("\nPrime numbers are : \n");

while (i<=num) {

    while (j<=i) {
        if (i%j==0)
            count++;
        j++;
        }

    if (count==2)
        printf ("%d\n",i);

    i++;
    count=0;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly depending on how big your entered number is it will get stuck in a loop forever.

Answer (score 2):

```
What is the error in the code ?
```

### Simple answer

You should be resetting `j` to 1 after testing each number `i` for primality.

```
i++;
count=0;
j = 1;
```

### Longer answer

You can reduce the runtime of this algorithm significantly.

By looping `j` up to the square root of `i`, you can make the prime check O(sqrt(i)) instead of O(i).

Since you are searching for prime numbers within a range, you can further speed up the algorithm by using a [prime number sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: I always miss such minor but vital things ! Thanks a lot.